# google spreadsheet rsvp

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-sheets

need idea from you all, currently i using google spreadsheet rsvp template and embed it into our application as iframe. in the spreadsheet rsvp template, there is a field to enter user-fullname. Is it possible to pass variable from outer-page into this iframe so that it populate the rsvp field user-fullname throught java script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [pre-populate fields](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160000) using the query string.  You just set the appropriate entry parameters (e.g. entry_0=John%20Smith).  The linked page has an example URL, `http://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?formkey=12345&entry_0=Barack&entry_1=Obama&entry_2=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave&entry_3=pistachios|spinach|broccoli&entry_4=8/4/1967`